# String Jquery ou JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal estou precisando de ajuda na seguinte logica, tenho uma String pergunta que sempre segue um padrão: O que é xxx xxx ou o que significa xxx xxx, gostaria de pegar sempre o xxx xxx.

Exemplo:

var pergunta1 = " O que é física nuclear";
var pergunta2 = " O que significa física nuclear"

na caso eu gostaria de pegar sempre o que esta após do o que é ou o que significa.

Obrigado,

Comment: Você quer apanhar sempre as 3 primeiras palavras é isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) do próprio javascript

```
oque = "o que é física nuclear";
significa = "o que significa física atômica";

cortaOque = oque.split("é")[1];
console.log(cortaOque); //saída: física nuclear

cortaSignifica = significa.split("significa")[1]; 
console.log(cortaSignifica); //saída: física atômica
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a função substring como descrito abaixo no código. Ela remove os 7 caracteres anteriores.Para saber mais sobre esta função veja o link [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp).

```js
    
       function myFunction() {
        var str = "O que é física nuclear";
        var res = str.substring(7);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <p>Click the button to extract characters from the string.</p>
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: A resposta do amigo la em baixo é um pouco complexa pois vai criar um array.

Answer (score 0):

vc pode fazer assim:
define duas variaveis, 
`var o_q_eh = 'O que é:'`
e 
`var o_q_significa = 'O que Significa ';`.
esperando q vc use a tag html label pra criar o texto da pergunta... `<label></label>` 
ficaria assim: `<label id="pergunta1">O que é física nuclear</label>`

use jquery pra pegar o text do `id="pergunta1"` usando: `var pergunta1 = $('#pergunta1').text();`
depois use `substring` para remover o q precisa, ou concatene as variaveis: `var o_q_eh;`e `var o_q_significa` com o resto do texto de cada `<label>` que precisa. se entendi o q precisa...